# Python code is too slow compared to MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

I have 10 matrices (1000x29). I want to generate all possible combinations with coefficients from 0 to 1, increment of 0.05 and sum of 1. That makes 10015005 combinations. Then I need to calculate the ordering rank, and save the last row.

Since there are many combination, I generate a table of coefficients first:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

start=datetime.now()

def frange(start, stop, step):
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i += step

col_names = ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7','x8','x9','x10']

#df = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((10015005,10)))
for x1 in frange(0,1,0.05):
    for x2 in frange(0,(1-x1),0.5):
        for x3 in frange(0,(1-x1-x2),0.05):
            for x4 in frange(0,(1-x1-x2-x3),0.05):
                for x5 in frange(0,(1-x1-x2-x3-x4),0.05):
                    for x6 in frange(0,(1-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5),0.05):
                        for x7 in frange(0,(1-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5-x6),0.05):
                            for x8 in frange(0,(1-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5-x6-x7),0.05):
                                for x9 in frange(0,(1-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5-x6-x7-x8),0.05):
                                    x10=1-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5-x6-x7-x8-x9
                                    df.loc[len(df)] = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10]
df.to_csv('template_10program_coef0.05.csv',index=False)
print(datetime.now() - start)
```

However, it runs for several days and end up with np.array MemoryError. I tried with Matlab and it finishes after several minutes.

There I have the table, I use multiprocessing to calculate smaller parts of the table

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from datetime import datetime

start=datetime.now()


#read template of coefficients
t1 = pd.read_csv("template_10program_coef0.05.csv")
t1.dropna()

#read docking scores
d1 = pd.read_csv("table_1.csv")
d2 = pd.read_csv("table_2.csv")
d3 = pd.read_csv("table_3.csv")
d4 = pd.read_csv("table_4.csv")
d5 = pd.read_csv("table_5.csv")
d6 = pd.read_csv("table_6.csv")
d7 = pd.read_csv("table_7.csv")
d8 = pd.read_csv("table_8.csv")
d9 = pd.read_csv("table_9.csv")
d10 = pd.read_csv("table_10.csv")

#number of core and divided matrices
n = 30

#length of sub-matrices
m = (len(open("template_10table_coef0.05.csv").readlines(  )) -1) // n


#function to calculate for each sub-matrices
def block_linear(i):

    temp = d1.iloc[0:0,:].copy() #create empty dataframe for ligand ranks

    for a in range(i*m,(i+1)*m):
        sum_matrix = abs(t1.iloc[a,0]*d1) + abs(t1.iloc[a,1]*d2) + abs(t1.iloc[a,2]*d3)+ abs(t1.iloc[a,3]*d4) +abs(t1.iloc[a,4]*d5) +abs(t1.iloc[a,5*d6) +abs(t1.iloc[a,6]*d7) +abs(t1.iloc[a,7]*d8) +abs(t1.iloc[a,8]*d9) +abs(t1.iloc[a,9]*d10)
        rank_sum= pd.DataFrame.rank(sum_matrix,axis=0,ascending=False,method='max') #calculate ranks for each cell, based on each column
        temp = temp.append(rank_sum.loc[999],ignore_index=True) #append last row (active ligand) to big dataframe
    temp['median'] = temp.median(axis=1) #median of 29 ligands to new column
    temp.index = range(i*m,(i+1)*m)
    return temp


#parse to multiple cores and merge
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pools = Pool(processes=n)
    list_b = range(0,n)
    resutls=pools.map(block_linear,list_b)
    pools.close()
    pools.join()
    results = pd.concat(pools)

#merge coefficients matrix and results matrix
t4 = pd.concat([t1,results],axis=1,sort=False)
#write to csv
t4.to_csv('result.csv',index=False)

print(datetime.now() - start)
```

The problem is again it runs for weeks without finishing. I tried with Matlab and it finishes after one day. What is the problem with my two codes that makes them run so long?

*Edit: Some comments help me to solve the first code, leaving the second only.*

Comment: Matlab is optimized for vectorized computation, it parallelizes a lot, if you feed the values as vectors / matrices. I don't know enough python to guarantee it, but the fact that you have so many nested `for` in your python code looks _very_ bad. You could at least get better results IMO if you try to use the "idiomatic" python list comprehension as much as possible.

Comment: You have 10 nested loops!?!!?!?!?! That should sound all the alarms in the world for inefficient.

Comment: Thank you @Pac0, I have solved the first code.